# Please explain the output of below array

Tags: php, arrays

Any one explain how comes **Array ( [1] => 4 )** output

```
$array = array(
        1 => "1",
        "1" => "2",
        1.5 => "3",
        true => "4",
    );
    print_r($array);
    output Array ( [1] => 4 )
```

Comment: All of those values type-juggle to integer `1`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-55

Comment: Just to be overly clear.. The output dump suggests that the value of the element is a number, `4` instead of `"4"`. But that's not the case, the value isn't changed and it's still 4, but as a string(the way it was initially, so unchanged).

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP array [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The key can either be an int or a string. The value can be of any type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Strings containing valid decimal ints, unless the number is preceded by a + sign, will be cast to the int type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.
> - Floats are also cast to ints, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.
> - Bools are cast to ints, too, i.e. the key true will actually be stored under 1 and the key false under 0.
> - Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".
> - Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

So the string `"1"`, flaot `1.5`, and bool `true` are all converted to the key `1`.